# Changing the content of li dynamically in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Trying to build a ajax comment system .I have a list populated from MYSQL database.And displaying that list works fine.but when user adds his comment the entire database gets appended to my already printed list.is there another method to empty the list first ?since appending will just append to the already created list.I want to clear the list first and then add again.

Comment: You want to completely rebuild the entire list of comments? Why not take the timestamp from your most recent comment, and use that to get all comments newer than it and append those onto your list? You could even remove the oldest comments for every new comment pulled down; this would keep an unchanging number of comments on the page at any given time.

Comment: even though that is a great/better option.I am doing a very small project and would prefer a simpler option (I have just msg field in my database) like refreshing the whole list or appending the new comments to the list(But,i agree that timestamp method will be optimal considering my resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.empty()`

```
selector.empty().append(data);
```

instead of just

```
selector.append(data);
```